# How to change the default log level for chef-client for all nodes

Tags: chef-infra

**Background**
We are grabbing all of our chef-client logs from our nodes (OS X laptops) using Splunk Universal Forwarder. We are putting these logs into several Splunk dashboards, since the Chef Server UI isn't the easiest to work with. *A little beside the point: I'm grabbing logs from the nodes directly because I'm not sure of a better way to grab the logs and get them into Splunk.*

**The Goal**
The logs that are created by default during the automatic chef-client runs are not verbose enough for my needs. [As outlined on Chef's documentation](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html#settings), the default value for log_level is set as :warn (when a terminal is available) or :info (when a terminal is not available). These situations fit the latter and thus log as :info. I would much rather they always log as :warn.

Unfortunately, I can't find anything in their documentation on how to do this. [From their chef-client readme](https://github.com/chef-cookbooks/chef-client#chef-client-config), I see that setting this using the attribute `node['chef_client']['log_level']` is now deprecated. It mentions setting them using `node['chef_client']['config']`, but I can't find documentation anywhere on using `node['chef_client']['config']`.

Thank you!

EDIT: We have hundreds of nodes and I need a Chef supported way to do this from an attribute or a cookbook (or whatever). I can't go in and manually change the log_level value on the client.rb files (which would just change back anyway, unless I figure out where to set change the default for this). And as mentioned, it looks like setting `node['chef_client']['log_level']` as :warn is now deprecated.

Comment: For clarity, the `chef-client` _cookbook_ (distinct from `chef-client` the command line program) is used to generate the `client.rb` config file described in the answer below, but you can also generate a config file other ways such as knife bootstrap or manually.

Answer (score 2):

The simple thing to do would be to just run `chef-client -l warn` but you've probably considered that already.

To do this in code, but without hacking Chef itself, a few minutes of playing UTSL makes me wonder: it might work to put the following in `/etc/chef/client.rb`:

```
Chef::Config[:log_level] = :warn
```

Comment: Why on earth using `Chef::Config` when it is actually the actual context ? the config file (`client.rb`) is loaded as a `Chef::config` instance, `log_level` is readily available without calling the Class explicitly. Your trick stands if you put this in a recipe and reload the config just after this call.

Comment: To summarize, the way you set log level in the client config like so: `log_level :warn`

Comment: Thank you for your reply! Unfortunately, I can't go into all of our computers and edit the client.rb file. There has to be some programmatic way to do this using Chef and I can't really find it. They used to just let you change the default['chef_client']['log_level'] attribute (which is deprecated now), which is what would change that setting in the client.rb file.

Answer (score 1):

Best method in my point of view:

Make a cookbook wrapping the [chef-client cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client), let's call it `my_company_chef-client`

Add a line `depends 'chef-client', '~> 4.6'` in `my_company_chef-client/metadata.rb`.

I leave the minor upgrades possible here as I'm quite confident in this cookbook quality and upgrade process, getting the cookbook available along with your own cookbook is a matter of taste, [berkshelf](http://berkshelf.com/) is the most commonly used as far as I know but discussing it would be out of scope for this answer.

In `my_company_chef-client/attributes/default.rb` :

```
default['chef-client']['config']['log_level'] = :warn
```

In `my_company_chef-client/recipes/default.rb` :

```
include_recipe 'chef-client::config'
```

Then just add the `my_company_chef-client` into all your nodes runlist. Trick taken from [here](http://dougireton.com/blog/2013/02/03/knife-tricks/) if you don't have a base role or wrapper for all your nodes:

```
knife exec -E 'nodes.find("*") {|n| puts n.run_list << "recipe[my_company_chef-client]" unless n.run_list.include?("recipe[my_company_chef-client]"); n.save }'
```

More details on the configuration [here](https://docs.chef.io/config_rb_client.html) and on the chef-client cookbook usage [here](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client#usage)

Comment: As I mentioned in my main post, apparently default['chef-client']['log_level'] is a deprecated attribute. :( So, it doesn't seem to be as simple as that anymore. That's the main reason I'm having problems. I can't figure out how to set them using node['chef_client']['config'], which is what they suggest is the "new way" to set this.

Comment: Sorry I forgot the config in between

Comment: Ohhhhh okay! So, could I just change this attribute at the role level? Since it would override whatever is the cookbooks sets for for default['chef-client']['config']['log_level']? NOTE: We already have the chef-client cookbook on our runlists.

Comment: @kama it is deprecated in favor of using the config parameter under the chef_client -> config level and now you can set any config parameter this way, hence the deprecation. sorry for the bad copy/paste in the answer, I've corrected it.

Comment: @kama yes, assuming you're using a recent version of the chef-client cookbook ;)

Comment: No problem, I can totally understand copypasta errors. Thank you for your help! I'll be trying it out today

Comment: @Kame sorry just noticed I misspelled the first letters of your name while commenting earlier, there's no auto completion on phone and I didn't pay enough attention, really sorry